# While Loop and Exiting of While Loop

Tags: java

```
import java.io.*; import java.util.*;
public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
    while(true)
    {
        Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Whats your name?");
        String s=kbReader.nextLine();
        String at=s.substring(0,1);
        if(at.equalsIgnoreCase("t"))
        {
            System.out.println("You're AWESOME!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You suck");
        }
    }
}
}
```

My code is a simple input code that asks to enter your name and looks at the first letter only and runs that through an if statement. Im using a while loop to loop the code endlessly. How would i have a line of code that would ask the person imputing Strings if they want to quit the while loop or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just do a `if` for a specific character or string and use `return` or `break`.

For example :

```
if (at.equalsIgnoreCase("Q")) {
    break;
}
```

**EDIT** : alternative could be to ask again the user at the end of the loop if he wants to continue :

```
System.out.println("Do you want to continue ? [Y]/N");
String s=kbReader.nextLine();
if (at.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can terminate the loop by capturing a particular character. You can provide that character on the `println` statement that inquires the name :

```
while(true)
{
    Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Whats your name? Or type # to end");
    String s=kbReader.nextLine();
    String at=s.substring(0,1);
    if(at.equalsIgnoreCase("#"))
    {
        break;
    }
    else if(at.equalsIgnoreCase("t"))
    {
        System.out.println("You're AWESOME!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("You suck");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Include an escape sequence, such as an integer, into the workflow:

```
String s=kbReader.nextLine();
if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("0") { // hopefully no one is named zero :)
  break;
}
String at=s.substring(0,1); ...
```

Answer (score 0):

in a more elegant way you can do a menu:

```
import java.io.*; import java.util.*;
public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
    while(true)
    {
        Scanner kbReader=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Whats your name?\nPress 0 to quit program");
        String s=kbReader.nextLine();
        String at=s.substring(0,1);
        if(at.equalsIgnorecase("0")){
        break;
        }
        if(at.equalsIgnoreCase("t"))
        {
            System.out.println("You're AWESOME!!!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("You suck");
       }
    }
}
}
```